# I want to release my mobile app freely, not release from AppStore and GooglePlay

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to release my mobile app(Flutter) freely to use it myself, but passing the application certification in AppStore and GooglePlay is so hard.

Is there any way to release my app?

Comment: You can put it on github.

Comment: Put your app on your own server.

Comment: Apple has locked down the phones.  Unless they are jailbroken, your app will need to go through TestFlight, and then you can post a public link to download them from the TestFlight section of the AppStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For yourself, just use adb install to install via command line.  For others, put the compiled apk file on a website somewhere.  It can be downloaded and installed, they just need to toggle a setting that prevents outside software.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you the way put the compiled apk file on a website somewhere?

Comment: I used DropBox for these.

Comment: Thank you, I try the way

Answer (score 1):

I've released 10+ app on GooglePlay, and as far as i know, if you want to publish your app there, you will need to follow all of their procedures. I personally don't think it is that difficult to fulfill all the requirements.

As an other alternative, you can simply upload your .apk file on your blog/site and tell people to download it from there.

However, using GooglePlay/AppStore as the platform to launch your app will give more credibility to your app, as people will tend to consider downloading from blog as 'not safe' (might be infiltrated by other unintended software).